# implementation of dequeue in python using linkedlist

Tags: python, linked-list, deque

I implemented a Dequeue using a simple list in python. However i need to implement a separate class for linked list and implement dequeue with that. For this pointer reference is needed at left and right ends. I don't know how to do this. Can some body provide some references or implementations..

Comment: In response to your comment, if this is a homework assignment, it should be tagged as such (that would then explain why you're not just using the already provided class).

Answer (score 2):

Any reason you're not just using the one from the library?  http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html

Comment: i implemented one using  the module "collections" (deque function), but inorder to learn more from basics am assigned to implement it with a "linkedlist" implementation as a class.